# jQuery custom function extend: store data into DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have this simple function

```
$.fn.extend({

    initCustomFunction: function(){

        var obj = { // some data }
        $(this).data('myObj', obj); // I want to attach obj to this element

    }, 

    startCustomFunction: function(){

        var obj = $(this).data('myObj');

        // do something

    }
});

$('#myId').initCustomFunction();
$('#myId').startCustomFunction();
```

In this example i cannot retrieve 'myObj' object inside 'startCustomFunction'. How can i solve this? I would like to attach some data to the current DOM element when i call my Init function on a specific element.

Comment: You missed a comma before `startCustomFunction`

Comment: Can't reproduce...with one element, but problem occurs when multiple elements are there, right?

Comment: It doesn't work with single or multiple element. I would like to reproduce a behaviour like many jQuery plugin where you want to init something on an element and then you can access to plugin's data on that element. I doesn't understand how to save my plug in data on the object where I call my init function. For example when I init a datatable on a div element I can access to datatable config using $(#div-element). DataTable

Comment: The problem was in the selector... The code above works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma between the two function definitions.

```js
$.fn.extend({

    initCustomFunction: function(){

        var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
        $(this).data('myObj', obj); // I want to attach obj to this element

    },

    startCustomFunction: function(){

        var obj = $(this).data('myObj');
        $('#result').text(obj.foo);

    }
});

$('#myId').initCustomFunction();
$('#myId').startCustomFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myId"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Correct. I changed my code but still not working. The obj is attached to local scope "this"..

Comment: My code snippet works. Please post an mcve so we can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve